# Getting Google sheets to give me the mode of a text for a specific user?

Tags: google-sheets, mode

So I play an air combat simulator with a group on Digital Combat Simulator AKA DCS, for fun. I was asked to create a spreadsheet on google to help keep track of a bunch of statistics, to better understand stuff like: what kills us the most? What weapon are we the most accurate with? What weapon are we the least accurate with, so and so...

[What I have and tried so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuH4f.png)

My issue right now is trying to get the spreadsheet to count up all the misses inputted into the spreadsheet for a certain person, in this case, Schmidt in aircraft 103, figure out which misses occur the most, in his case, the type of miss that occurs the most is "Energy Defeated" and then display it in the column that says "missile Defeat mode". This is specific to a person, so that's an additinal condition that I am having trouble programming for.

Thank you for your time and help.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cz1o06slDFuOCYnp8qlzF4icpscgEblHuJff7HAOXnY/edit?usp=sharing

here is a dummy spreadsheet if you want to look into the details.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please, besides adding an image to show what you tried, add the sample data and formulas as text.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are matching the Pilot column, you need to use QUERY statements to gather the dataset, then ARRAY_CONSTRAIN to limit to what you want to display.

### Formula

```
=iferror(
  ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
    query(
      query(
         {$A$21:$A$33,$L$21:$L$33},
         "select Col2, count(Col2) where Col1='"&A4&"' 
         group by Col2 order by count(Col2) desc limit 1"
         ,)
    ,"offset 1",)
  ,1,1)
 ,"")
```

*Breaking this down:*
The first thing that happens is you run a query against the Pilot and Outcome columns (A21:A33,L21:L33) based on the Pilot (A4) to find the outcomes (Col2), count each, then sort them in descending order so that the most common is listed first. Limit the return to just the top reason. This will produce a 2x2 array of results.

```
|                  | count |
| ---------------- | ----- |
| Sensor Defeated  | 2     |
```

So we run the second query to remove the first row:

```
| Sensor Defeated  | 2  |
```

Then, Array_Constrain lets us lop off the second column (containing the count of times that outcome was found), leaving just the most-found outcome:

```
Sensor Defeated
```

It's all wrapped up in a nice iferror statement so you can have blanks if the pilot isn't found in the query range.

Just copy that formula into each cell in G2 - G16 and you're good to go.

### Example

Here is the formula in action on a [copy of your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gugWdQn09HDosPSu1mX74n8Gw5A5gRCX6uAd5wh6e6w/edit?usp=sharing).